# Azure Cognitive Search - Requiring Minimum Match Count per Result

Tags: .net-core, azure-cognitive-search

I have an index with many fields, 10 of which are searchable, and each search query includes all 10 fields, where I'm using Lucene syntax and explicitly searching each of the 10 fields for a specific value.  The goal is to find records where at least 3 of the 10 fields are a match.

So far the best I could come up with is to include each of the 10 fields in the HighlightFields list, and then count the highlights when I get the result back.  This accomplishes the primary goal, but I've been trying to find a way to prevent the lesser-matched documents from even being returned.

As far as I can tell, this is not a thing, but I'm hoping someone could tell me I'm wrong.

(If there's a cloud service better suited for this problem, I'd love to hear suggestions!)

Comment: Can you explain why you want to find records with matches in three properties? What’s the use case? Perhaps we can suggest alternative approaches that resolves the use case!

Answer (score 0):

Azure Cognitive Search does not support a "minimum field match" filter on queries currently. Achieving this will require some client-side processing either by using highlighting, or the returned document directly.

Since the document with matches in more fields is going to be ranked higher, scanning the document list should inevitably allow you to find the cutoff document which doesn't satisfy the criteria if any.